# Group information reported wrong for a specific user

Tags: users, group, nis

I have a problem on a server I manage. An account (specifically, my account) does not seem to have the correct groups. I think the problem is most easily demonstrated by looking at the following command sequence:

```
Last login: sometime from somewhere
user.x@srv:~$ groups
user.x
user.x@srv:~$ groups user.x
user.x : user.x grp1 grp2
user.x@srv:~$ su - user.x
Password:
user.x@srv:~$ groups
user.x grp1 grp2
user.x@srv:~$ exit
user.x@srv:~$ groups
user.x
```

So the problem is that the groups for user.x are incorrectly reported after logging in (through SSH). If logging in is simulated again (`su -`) or the username is supplied with the `groups` or `id` command it works fine.

The incorrect groups cause all sorts of problems, like not being able to sudo. How can I fix this?

Further information that might be relevant:

- The server is a NIS client which synchronises every 15 minutes
- The problem is rare, but not unique, at the moment 2 users have acquired it in the last half-year
- The problem seems to only happen to users that SSH into the machine often

Comment: What is the situation when you log in and then run `/bin/bash --login` instead of `su -`?

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz Then the group information is invalid too. The same holds true for ```/bin/dash -l```

Comment: This looks like some broken configuration then, probably something in `/etc/profile` - see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the group information was first pulled from nis and then from the local copies of the nis (made by ypserv)

The solution was changing /etc/nsswitch.conf from

```
group: compat
```

to:

```
group: files nis compat
```

Answer (score 0):

Group permissions are set at the time the shell is created. The very first shell where `groups` output only shows `user.x`, was that shell created before adding the other groups? If so simply log out and log in again.

Comment: The groups were created long before this particular SSH session was started. The commands are literately run after logging in.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a problem with the user shells' configurations. Check how the shells are defined in `/etc/passwd` and inspect the `/etc/profile`, users' login scripts (like `.bashrc`, `.bash_login`, `.profile` etc.) for any errors. If you don't find anything that would fix it, backup those files and restore default ones. Possibly re-install the shell(s).